# Invalid classes inferred from unique values of `y`. Expected: [0 1], got ['N' 'Y']

Tags: data-science

```
Invalid classes inferred from unique values of `y`.  Expected: [0 1], got ['N' 'Y']
```

anyone can help me out with this problem it is Xgboost problem i solve this with label encoding but for further steps i face problems

Answer (score 0):

Just encode your "y" column because the model expects the column to be predicted as categorical:

```
df["y"] = df["y"].astype('category').cat.codes
```